# Show conditionally a div with color in angular if browser is other than Google chrome

Tags: angular, typescript

As i am planning to display a div if any user accesses the web page other than Google chrome then i want to show a message that currently we dont support other browsers. We support only Google chrome. I want to achieve this in Angular 8. Can anyone help me in this regard?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should generally not do this, it serves very little purpose and from a product perspective damages your relationship with your users because it sends the message you don't care about their choices. As Mozilla put it in their article on [user-agent sniffing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent):

> Serving different Web pages or services to different browsers is usually a bad idea. The Web is meant to be accessible to everyone, regardless of which browser or device they're using. There are ways to develop your website to progressively enhance itself based on the availability of features rather than by targeting specific browsers.

You *should* instead detect for features and then provide a degraded experience (possibly with a notice to say that not all features required for the site are supported by the user's browser).

---

Saying that, just look up the user agent string from the user agent string from the HTTP Headers if this logic is located on a server, or by using [`navigator.userAgent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorID/userAgent) on the front-end. There are a wide variety of libraries which will parse this into a consistent format for you.